# Сохранение ip пользователя моего веб-сайта

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, ip

Я пишу веб-сайт на flask. Мне необходимы логи, я все настроил. Работает все пока локально, когда появляется необходимость я расшариваю сервер через njrok. В логах должен быть айпи адрес клиента. Когда я использую request.remote_addr, мне выводит айпи локалхоста. Если расшарить через njrok ничего не меняется, абсолютно все адреса распознаются как 127.0.0.1. Что мне делать, чтобы сохранялся РЕАЛЬНЫЙ ВНЕШНИЙ айпи адрес?

Comment: Как запускаете? Перед Flask что-то стоит?

Comment: Попробуйте так: `request.environ['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`. В целом, это зависит от того, что проксирует Ваш запрос.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло!